# How does the delegate invocation list is built?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to understand how combining delegates works. In the following code, I changed the usual implementation of `set` (with a simple assignment, using `=` operator) into an ill-formed one (by using the `+=` operator).

So the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Cooler
{
    public void OnTemperatureChanged(float newTemperature) {}
}

class Heater
{
    public void OnTemperatureChanged(float newTemperature) {}
}

public class Thermostat
{
    private Action<float> _OnTemperatureChange;

    public Action<float> OnTemperatureChange
    {
        get
        { return _OnTemperatureChange; }
        set
        {
            _OnTemperatureChange += value; // note the += 
        }
    }

    public void PrintRegistered()
    {
        if (OnTemperatureChange != null)
        {
            foreach (Delegate existingHandler in _OnTemperatureChange.GetInvocationList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(existingHandler.Target + "." + existingHandler.Method);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Thermostat thermostat = new Thermostat();
        Heater heater = new Heater();
        Cooler cooler = new Cooler();

        thermostat.OnTemperatureChange += cooler.OnTemperatureChanged;
        thermostat.OnTemperatureChange += heater.OnTemperatureChanged;
        thermostat.PrintRegistered();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
```

Of course, If I change back the `set` to its usual implementation, we'll see a single `OnTemperatureChanged` for `Cooler` and `Heater`.

I'd like to understand why setting the delegate this way resulted in this form of invocation list?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be using an event here? This is exactly the scenario events are designed for.

Comment: Helter Skelter is a nice episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` for delegates calls `Delegate.Combine`. `thermostat.OnTemperatureChange += cooler.OnTemperatureChanged;` calls this twice: Once in `Main` and once in `set_OnTemperatureChange`. So it's a banal bug that causes the side effect two times.

`thermostat.OnTemperatureChange += cooler.OnTemperatureChanged` adds `Cooler`.

`thermostat.OnTemperatureChange += heater.OnTemperatureChanged` takes `Cooler`, converts it into `Cooler, Heater`, then calls `set` which combines it with the old value causing this to become `Cooler, Cooler, Heater`.

I admit I found this very unintuitive but it's due to a banal bug.

Adding a 3rd heater line results in:

```
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
```

Adding another heater line results in:

```
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Cooler.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
Heater.Void OnTemperatureChanged(Single)
```

It always keeps the same prefix, the the same prefix again, then heater.

If you want a recommendation: Use `event Action<float> OnTemperatureChange;` and this goes away.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate why using an `event` eliminates this?

Comment: `operator+=` on events calls the `add` accessor. It does not itself combine delegates. I primarily suggested using event because it captures your intent better. The bug can be removed in multiple way, event is just one.